# Can't select button to click on it using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am a newbie in selenium, and I got stock when I want to click the button with the next html code :

```
<div class="mb-8">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <button class="w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ">
    <div class="font-medium">
    <div class="text-17 md:text-18 md:font-bold leading-18">Activate</div> 
    <div class="text-13 md:text-12 font-normal md:font-medium leading-normal">Mining 4 hours</div>
    </div>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tryed :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://link")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
search.clear()
search.send_keys("username")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
search.clear()
search.send_keys("password")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)
link= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Miner")
link.click()
time.sleep(3)
link= driver.find_element_by_class_name("w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ")
```

Got this:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

```
link=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ")
```

Same error.
Tryed also this (because of the info in the image)

[image]

```
link=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".w-full.h-14.pt-2.pb-1.px-3.bg-accent.text-dark-1.rounded-full.md\:rounded.select-none.cursor-pointer.md\:hover\:shadow-big.focus\:outline-none.md\:focus\:bg-accent-2.md\:focus\:shadow-small.")
```

Same error.
Tryed this also:

```
link= driver.find_element_by_class_name("Activate")
```

Got this :

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Activate"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

Thank you for your help !!!

Answer (score 2):

If none of these work your element is in an iframe. driver.switch_to.frame() would solve it.

Xpaths:

```
//div[@class='wrapper']/button
//div[.='Activate']/parent::button[1]
```

Css selectors:

```
button.w-full.h-14.pt-2.pb-1.px-3.bg-accent.text-dark-1.rounded-full.md:rounded.select-none cursor-pointer.md:hover:shadow-big.focus:outline-none.md:focus:bg-accent-2 .md:focus:shadow-small
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an element by class then just use one class instead of all classes.

Here in your case 'Activate' is not a class. You can try:

```
link= driver.find_element_by_class_name("w-full");
```

Also, you can find this button using XPath.

Comment: Tryed link= driver.find_element_by_class_name("w-full"), but I got this error    NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".w-full"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)

Comment: Ohh ok, Can you please try with the class name 'mb-8' or 'wrapper'. If it does not work then you can try XPath , With XPath , it should definitely work.-.  [John](https://www.dotnetguide.com/xamarin/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're still struggling with this task I have posted the answer on a different post [Find the button element for selenium Automation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358642/find-the-button-element-for-selenium-automation-in-python/66405101#66405101) be sure to check it out.