# Find the button element for selenium Automation in python

Tags: python, selenium, button

I have inspected the element and got the following code.
This button "Activate" appears only once in 4 hours. To run the process I need to find this element.

I tried using:

1. `find_element_by_class_name`
2. `find_element_by_link_text`

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<button class="w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ">
<div class="font-medium">
<div class="text-17 md:text-18 md:font-bold leading-18">Activate</div> 
<div class="text-13 md:text-12 font-normal md:font-medium leading-normal">to run process</div></div>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should search and refresh a page until an element popsup.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='wrapper']/div[.='Activate']")))
        break
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue for that particular website and I have finally been able to solve it. What I did is find the 'iframe' of the website through Chromes inspect element tool.

This is where you will find the iframe source:

[image]

Once you discover this, code the following:

```
    while True:
    try: 
        self.driver.get("Enter Iframe src here")
        time.sleep(4)
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper > .w-full").click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(10)
```

Do note that there may be a better way to do this by dynamically getting the iframe src. But this should work.